# Which poison makes seastars inedible to possible predators?

Tags: marine-biology, ecophysiology, invertebrates

In the new citizen science project (see: [Sea Floor Explorer](http://www.seafloorexplorer.org/)), numbers of seastars, scallops, crustaceans and other animals are counted. Already one can see a heavy bias in favor of seastars, both the fat and brittle kind.

I would be interested in why this creature is so succesful, especially if it is poisonous to e.g., crustaceans, and what poisons exactly are responsible.

Comment: it may not be that they are poisonous. seastars have extraordinary reproductive capabilities

Comment: That is the other factor of success. But they are really poisonous, see the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Asterosaponins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown-of-thorns_starfish#Toxins) are the class of compounds - [they have a cholesterol like organic core](http://books.google.com/books?id=8Ugmrew2EqEC&pg=PA314&lpg=PA314&dq=asterosaponins&source=bl&ots=RF4cXY5Myb&sig=pSz43IVy6FaSorNFzQT01jsHj-8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XwZVUNaiB6jmiwKv_oGwDQ&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=asterosaponins&f=false).

Apparently, these saponins make **pore-forming** complexes with Δ<sup>5</sup>-sterols of cell membranes, and so are deadly to all usual kind of life, including bacteria and fungi. Quote:

> Starfish and sea cucumber cell membranes are resistant to their own
>   saponines due to the presence of Δ<sup>7</sup>- and
>   Δ<sup>9,11</sup>-sterols, sulfated Δ<sup>5</sup>-sterols, and
>   β-xylosides of sterols instead of the free Δ<sup>5</sup>-sterols.